# AJAX, JSON, jQuery, and PHP

Tags: php, json, jquery

I know there are alot of different questions about this but none of them seem to pertain to me. I have an ajax request as follows:

```
var responsePacket;
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    type:'POST',
    data:{
        "updatePacket":{
            "job":"name-update",
            "firstName":firstName,
            "lastName":lastName
        }
    },
    processData: false,
    url:'modify.php',
    success: function(json){
        console.log(json);
        responsePacket = json;

        if(responsePacket.updateStatus==true){
            genAlertAlignAndShow('Name Successfully Updated', false, 4000);
        }
        else{
            genErrorAlignAndShow('Name Update Failed!', false, 4000);
        }
    }
})
```

And my PHP on the other end are as follows:

```
$updatePacket = json_decode($_POST['updatePacket'], true);
//and I access variables from the JSON Object like this:
$job = $updatePacket['job'];
```

In response to the AJAX, the PHP file will punch out a simple JSON object, and yes my headers are set to `application/json`. This is how I a output a JSON response, I have tested it and it appears to get back to the AJAX Request when I rig it to return a static response:

```
$responsePacket = array("updateStatus"=>true);
echo json_encode($responsePacket);
```

**But Here Is The Problem**
As you can see I output the data to the console, but all it says is `null` which I have deduced is indicative of the JSON not getting to the PHP correctly. So, is there a proper way to create JSON Objects and prepare an AJAX request that will get the data to the PHP script intact.

I have been grappling with this problem for about 3 hours now, ANY suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I've copied to code above and create a file named `modify.php` and your code seems to work fine for me. I was able to see that `updateStatus` is `true`. Do you have an `if` statement somewhere that handles a case when `updateStatus` is `false`? Is is possible that the problem lies there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is my AJAX Requst:

```
$.post('modify.php', { job: "name-update", lastName: lastName }, function(data){
    console.log(data);
})
```

**The Problem:**
When declaring data for an AJAX Post request putting quotes on the variable names will make the variables inaccessible to the receiving script.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `$_POST['updatePacket']` is not actually a json string. Try to access it like this instead:

```
$updatePacket = $_POST['updatePacket'];
$job = $updatePacket['job'];
```

No need to `json_decode()` it. From the [`json_decode()` manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) (return value):

> NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded...

Give it a try. As mentioned in the comments, `var_dump($_POST);` should be the first thing you try, to ensure you're getting what you think you are.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make the time consuming issue of getting form data in a clean way with jquery, or javascript alone.

All you need to do is .serialize() the data.  An example is here.

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log( $( this ).serialize() );
});
```

Once it is done you can transform a string that looks like this.

```
"param1=someVal&param2=someOtherVal"
```

with this

```
$params = array();
parse_str($_GET, $params);
```

with this usage you also want to filter the data and you should do this prior to the above.

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php
```

Do this is less time consuming then listing each one individually in your ajax.  You can also create a function to do this so you aren't continually writing ajax boilerplate code.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing it wrong. You don't send a JSON object to the server, you send key/value pairs. And it's what jQuery expects. Do it like this instead:

```
data: {
    "job": "name-update",
    "firstName": firstName,
    "lastName": lastName
},
```

and access the values like this:

```
$job = $_POST['job'];
```

Comment: This is not the only way to do it.  If you have a large form it would be much easier to serialize the form.  That is why the function exists.  It also gives you the ability to use a function repeatedly.

Comment: Why the down vote? Based on his example he was doing it wrong. Just take a look at the accepted answer and compare to mine! He got it write but the "why" is wrong. You should go and down vote that too!